# How to clear polyline when tap on another marker

Tags: java, android

I am creating an app and i am drawing a route from current marker to nearby markers. when i tap on nearby marker it created a route, and when i again tap on another marker previous route still show. so i want to remove the previous route and draw a new route from current marker to nearby marker. Please help me using my source code....

```
mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

                    @Override
                    public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {

                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

                        //for direction Route

                        if(CurrentMarker != null) {
                            LatLng origin = CurrentMarker.getPosition();
                            LatLng dest = marker.getPosition();

                            String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);

                            DownloadPar downloadPar = new DownloadPar();

                            // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                            downloadPar.execute(url);

                        }


                        View myContentsView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.details, null);
                        TextView tvTitle = ((TextView)myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.title));
                        tvTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());
                        TextView tvSnippet = ((TextView)myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.snippet));
                        tvSnippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());


                        return myContentsView;



                    }
                });
```

Please help me...
Thanks

Comment: You need to keep hold of the previous polyline and set the map to null to remove it like so `polyline.setMap(null)`

Comment: getting error on "setMap"

Comment: can you please show it into my code

Comment: This is probably because when you create your polyline from `PolylineOptions` you're not keeping your `Polyline` referenced. I can't remember the syntax from the top of my head. Please share where you display/create your `Polyline`

Comment: protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
            PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;

Comment: You're not even creating a `Polyline`? From the code you've shared, no polyline is created/displayed

Comment: please show it i update in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a variable:

```
private Polyline polyline;
```

Then in your method when you initially add the `Polyline` to the `Map`:

```
polyline = mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
```

Then when you want to update the `Polyline` I believe you can use:

```
polyline.setPoints(newPoints);
```

Otherwise, remove the polyline by calling `polyline.setMap(null)` and create a new one like you have done above.

For more information regarding `Polyline`, see the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline.html#setPoints(java.util.List%3Ccom.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng%3E))

Answer (score 0):

protected void onPostExecute(List>> result) {
            ArrayList points = null;

```
        PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;

        // MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        //markerOptions.position(latLng);
        // markerOptions.title("Find Location");
        //  markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
        // FindMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        // Traversing through all the routes
        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();


            // Fetching i-th route
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

            // Fetching all the points in i-th route
            for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                points.add(position);
            }


            // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
            lineOptions.addAll(points);
            lineOptions.width(8);
            lineOptions.color(Color.GRAY);


        }

        // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
        mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);



    }

}
```